# PHP Get X Amount of Lines from File until Done

Tags: php, arrays, file

I have a text file with 2000 lines and need to get 100 at a time in a continuous loop. I can get it to work, but I have to manually change $i value for each chunk of 100. Here is the code:

```
    $file = 'postcode_2000.txt';
    for ($i = 0; $i <= 99; $i++) {

        $str = str_replace(PHP_EOL, '', $file[$i]);
        $list[] = $str;

    }

    $list_json = json_encode($list);
```

How can I iterate over this getting the next 100 each time?

Comment: Can't you use something like [`array_chunk()`](http://php.net/array-chunk) to break your large array into smaller pieces?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the file in an array you can use `array_chunk()`. First read the [file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) into an array:

```
$lines = 'postcode_2000.txt';
```

Then [chunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) the file into 100 line parts:

```
$chunks = array_chunk($lines, 100, true); // true keeps a set of consecutive line numbers
```

The output will be something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => line in file
            [1] => line in file
            [2] => line in file
            [3] => line in file
            [4] => line in file
            ...
            [94] => line in file
            [95] => line in file
            [96] => line in file
            [97] => line in file
            [98] => line in file
            [99] => line in file
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [100] => line in file
            [101] => line in file
            [102] => line in file
            [103] => line in file
            [104] => line in file
            ...
            [194] => line in file
            [195] => line in file
            [196] => line in file
            [197] => line in file
            [198] => line in file
            [199] => line in file
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [200] => line in file
            [201] => line in file
            [202] => line in file
            [203] => line in file
            [204] => line in file
            ...
            [294] => line in file
            [295] => line in file
            [296] => line in file
            [297] => line in file
            [298] => line in file
            [299] => line in file
        )
    ...    
    [18] => Array
        (
            [1800] => line in file
            [1801] => line in file
            [1802] => line in file
            [1803] => line in file
            [1804] => line in file
            ...
            [1894] => line in file
            [1895] => line in file
            [1896] => line in file
            [1897] => line in file
            [1898] => line in file
            [1899] => line in file
        )

    [19] => Array
        (
            [1900] => line in file
            [1901] => line in file
            [1902] => line in file
            [1903] => line in file
            [1904] => line in file
            ...
            [1994] => line in file
            [1995] => line in file
            [1996] => line in file
            [1997] => line in file
            [1998] => line in file
            [1999] => line in file
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use loops instead of [array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) :)

```
<?php

$file = file('/tmp/postcodes_2000.txt');

$list = array();
$line_count = count($file);
$chunk_size = 100;
$current_line = 0;
echo "Line count: ${line_count}" . PHP_EOL;
while( $current_line < $line_count ) {
  $i = 0;
  $chunk = array();
  while($i < $chunk_size) {
    $str = str_replace(PHP_EOL, '', $file[$current_line]);
    $chunk[] = $str;
    echo "> Line ${current_line} : " . $file[$current_line] . PHP_EOL;
    $i++;
    $current_line++;
  }
  $list[] = $chunk;
}

$list_json = json_encode($list);
echo $list_json . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: Your code prints out a single array with 2000 lines in it and does not chunk anything.

Comment: Sorry, was the old code for some reason, just updated the answer

Comment: Ignore my last comment, I typo'd your code in the test

Answer (score 0):

Generators are great for when you are calculating large sets and you don’t want to allocate memory for all of the results at the same time or when you don’t know if you will need all of the results, Due to the way results are processed, the memory footprint can be reduced to a very bare minimum by allocating memory for only the current result.

So this is a very fast way which consume less memory to achieve your goal:

we open the file ,read  a precise amount of lines and then yield the result while keeping the state for the next iteration and thus allow you to handle your chunks very fast and with less memory consumption.

Proceeding this way has the advantage to avoid reading all the file twice to build chunks (read it one time to build a big array containing all the lines and then loop through this array to build chunks) before allowing you finally (a third time) to loop through the array of chunks...

```
function file_get_x_lines($file,$amount=100){
    if(!file_exists($file)||!is_file($file)||!is_readable($file))
        return;
    if(!is_int($amount)||$amount<1) $amount=1;
    $handle=fopen($file,'rb');
        $i=0;
        while($line=fgets($handle)){
            if($i===0)
                $tmp=array();
            $chunks[]=rtrim($line,PHP_EOL);
            $i++;
            if($i===$amount){
                $i=0;
                $tmp=$chunks;
                $chunks=array();
                yield $tmp;
            }
        }
        if(!$line)
            yield $chunks; 

    }
```

then you can  use it like you would use any generator

```
foreach(file_get_x_lines(__FILE__) as $list)    {
    $list=json_encode($list);
    //do stuff
}
```

if you want to keep same keys as the line number you can lightly alter the function this way:

```
function file_get_x_lines($file,$amount=100){
        if(!file_exists($file)||!is_file($file)||!is_readable($file))
            return;
        if(!is_int($amount)||$amount<1) $amount=1;
        $handle=fopen($file,'rb');
            $i=0;
            $j=1;
            while($line=fgets($handle)){
                if($i===0)
                     $tmp=array();
                $chunks[$j]=rtrim($line,PHP_EOL);
                $i++;
                $j++;
                if($i===$amount){
                    $i=0;
                    $tmp=$chunks;
                    $chunks=array();
                    yield $tmp;
                }
            }
            if(!$line)
                yield $chunks; 

}
```

Comment: How does this consume less memory?

Comment: @jayBlanchard do this consume more memory according to you?

Comment: You stated it used less memory, so I just wanted to know how it used less memory.